# No matter how many times I try re-installing Linux Mint, I get a GRUB error. How do I fix it?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, upgrade, grub2

I have been trying to install Linux Mint 16 Petra using a removable USB thumb drive on my laptop, and after multiple attempts, I get the same error every time:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I tried following the instructions [here](http://forum.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=140479), but absolutely none of it helped.

How do I get my computer to boot?

Comment: So you can boot from USB, but get the grub error on 'normal' boot.  Like the thread you gave a link to, are there initial boot options from USB?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: With the USB thumb drive connected, the only options are to boot from the USB drive or run some memory tests. Nothing that can help the GRUB error.

Comment: There are no boot options from USB?  E.g., BIOS vs UEFI?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Nope. Should there be?

Comment: There doesn't have to be, but choosing specific USB boot options, and install from USB was the ultimate solution for the original poster of the link you provided.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Yeah. Where he mentions `UEFI:USB MEDIA`, and `USB MEDIA`, I don't see where that applies in any of the options I have.

Comment: Where did you get your USB image?  Have a link?  Perhaps best to include all these extra details in your original post.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: I used the `USB Image Writer` program in Linux Mint to copy the install ISO file to the thumb drive.

Comment: So the install proceeded completely normally, got to the "Restart Now" part, you clicked it, removed the thumb drive, and then got the mentioned error?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Yep, that's pretty much the case.

Comment: If you boot from USB and as root run 'grub-install /dev/sda' (if that's the proper device), does a reboot then work normally?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Maybe... I don't know what's happening right now, but I can't seem to boot from the USB thumb drive now either. I've checked the BIOS settings and I should be able to. It's possible my thumb drive has died, so I'm going to have to get another one to try.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Okay, after some unrelated complications, I was able to get the thumb drive to boot again. I ran `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` at a terminal prompt, and the response I got was `grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow. Path '/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.` I'm pretty sure my GRUB should be on `/dev/sda`, but I tried /dev/sda1` just as an experiment, and got the same response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to boot the computer using the USB stick, and then run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), which I only just learned about.

It was easy to install via repository, and the process was very clear. It [reported an error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6467676/), but the computer was able to reboot successfully anyway.

In the GRUB menu, the default option says `ubuntu` instead of Linux Mint, but I can live with that.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it.  Waiting for a Mint kernel update or running 'sudo update-grub' may "fix" the grub Ubuntu listing.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Thank you for all your suggestions and help along the way. Strangely, the GRUB listing seems to have corrected itself, though I can't be sure why or how. Likely it was something to do with some updates I did with the GUI update manager, but I couldn't tell you exactly what.

Answer (score -1):

Use these lines in **menu.lst** from grub4dos USb boot:

```
#  #  #
find --set-root /linuxmint.iso
map (hd0) (hd1)
map (hd1) (hd0)
map --mem /firadisk.img (fd1)
map --mem (md)0x6000+800 (fd0)
map --mem /linuxmint.iso (0xff)
map --hook
dd if=(fd1) of=(fd0) count=1
chainloader (0xff)
#  #  #
```

PS:

1. linuxmint.iso work with install of any OS iso
2. firadisk.iso is a virtual iso(google it)

Comment: 1)  He doesn't have grub4dos, 2) he isn't trying to boot the iso image, and 3) dd is not a grub command.

Answer (score -2):

look at diddy manual. He has the command cc there

diddy.boot-land.net/firadisk/files/win_iso_install.htm

also last guide on this page called "Using dd to edit sectors"

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/grub4dos#TOC-grub4dos-undocumented-commands

then please comment